# Can't connect to RDP from Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have created an instance of Windows server 2008 but it does not connect to RDP..........

I tried by using Remote Desktop Connection and RDP Extension of Chrome, but it ended with the same result.

It just displays that "Chrome does not connect to  "

Should I do some changes with firewall or anything else????

[How to Launch Windows VM Instance on Google Compute Engine.](http://www.mediaagility.com/2014/launching-windows-vm-instance-on-google-compute-engine/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should first check that port 3389 is open on the GCE firewall. If not, run a command like this to create the rule `$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create rdp --allow tcp:3389 --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0` . More info is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows#logging_into_a_windows_virtual_machine_instance).

Also, make sure you have the right username and password. This was set when you first created the instance. To check, please run `$ gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE_NAME --zone ZONE` and it will give you the initial user and password.

Comment: Did you make sure you have the right username and password by running the gcloud command ? Also, try to ping the IP and see if you reach the machine. Another way to test the firewall is to telnet to port 3389 : $ telnet IP 3389.

Comment: Google Compute RDP with Windows Servers blows, I've been using it for over a year and whenever you create a new instance, it will not connect. It's hit or miss, total disaster.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance).

Specifically I had to:

[Install gcloud/CLOUD SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)

Run this command:

```
gcloud compute reset-windows-password windows-instance
```

Then connect using the user and password that was generated.